# How to convert complex objects into one lighter object in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have some Illustrator art, and it's too complex (it has too many objects in it). It's too hard for the hardware to render it.

How can I convert all those objects into one to make it lighter?

[image: complex]

Comment: its the same when i create it as an symbol. ive try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can create a **symbol** and use symbols rather than duplicating objects repeatedly.
- You can create a **pattern** and fill shapes with patterns rather than repeatedly duplicating items.

Both these options allow Illustrator to reference 1 instance of the artwork and repeat it. However, there are some editing restrictions. You'll need a new pattern for every separate color you want, or you'll need to duplicate and adjust symbols for color variations.